# Passing a gravity forms hook variable into another gravity forms hook

Tags: php, gravityforms

There is a post of a similar name but the answer shown there is not working for me.

i'm trying to get the $user_id of the user as they register for my site and use that variable in a subsequent after form submission hook 
so

```
add_action( 'gform_user_registered', 'send_user_email', 10, 4 );
function send_user_email($user_id, $feed, $user_pass) {}
```

is the hook with the $user_id variable

```
add_action("gform_after_submission_1", "input_fields1", 10, 2);
function input_fields1($entry, $form) {}
```

is the hook to use to use to  process the form data after submission.

i have tried the follwing:

```
add_action( 'gform_user_registered', 'send_user_email', 10, 4 );
function send_user_email($user_id, $feed, $user_pass) {
var_dump($user_id.' '. 'a');
add_action("gform_after_submission_1", "input_fields1", 10, 2);
function input_fields1($entry, $form) {
global $user_id;
var_dump($user_id.' '.'b');
}
}
```

this returns "29 a" which is the first Var_dump and " b" but not "29 b" which is what i would expect for the second var_dump

is my PHP wrong or have i miss understood how these hooks work?

i also tried

```
add_action("gform_after_submission_1", "input_fields1", 10, 2);
function input_fields1($entry, $form) {

add_action( 'gform_user_registered', 'send_user_email', 10, 4 );
function send_user_email($user_id, $feed, $user_pass) {
var_dump($user_id.' '. 'a');
}
    global $user_id;
    var_dump($user_id.' '.'b');
}
```

this returns " b" without the variable and no " a" at all

Comment: You need to _assign_ your value to the global variable in the first function, if the second one is supposed to have access to it. (And you’ll want to use a different name for the function parameter, and the global variable, otherwise that’s going to lead to trouble.)

Answer (score 1):

i now realise that i don't need to do this. The 'gform_user_registered' hook also contains the same $entry variable i was trying to use in conjunction with the $user_id variable so these is no need to move the variable between hooks, as i can do eveything i need to do within the one hook function.